# Search 5 keywords in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, search, full-text-search, sql-like

I'm trying to search keywords from tags users input in a MySQL table, and return the best result based on the number of matches.

Code:

MySQL structure:

```
 id    | keywords       | phrase
 1     | apple king pearl   | I was eating an apple when the king hit me
 2     | brush brute fancy  | you fancy this brush?   
 3     | king queen kingdom | shall the queen obey the king or the kingdom?
```

PHP:

```
 $keywords_raw='me wall like king apple'   //define keywords based on the tags the user inputs
 $keywords=explode(' ', $keywords_raw);
```

....
That's where I got stuck. My ideass are:

1. the search would be performed on each keyword such as "me", "wall", "like" and so on
2. for each keyword, it would search through both columns "keywords" and "phrase" in each row of the table, and return the number of matches found. For example, searching keywords inputted against the first row would return that keywords "me" has 0 matches, "wall" has 0 matches, "like" 0, "king" 2 and "apple" 2. Thus the total matches would be 2+2 = 4.
3. At the end, compare the total number of matches found from all rows, and pick the top 3 rows that have the most matches.

A side question to #2 would be how to ignore words that contain the keyword searched, such as "kingdom" that contains "king" but is a different word.

---

Update:

following the helpful answers, I have used fulltext search.

```
    $keywords='bb';

    $data['recommendation']=$this->db->query
    ("SELECT *, MATCH(keywords, phrase) AGAINST ('$keywords') as score 
    FROM game
    WHERE MATCH(keywords, phrase) AGAINST ('$keywords') 
    ORDER BY score 
    LIMIT 3");

    var_dump($data['recommendation']);
    die;
```

for some reason var_dump returns an empty result with no row found. But I do have the phrase 'bb' in at least 2 rows of the table as below.

```
 id    | keywords       | phrase
 1     | bb king        | I was eating an apple when bb the king hit me
 2     | bb             | you fancy this brush?
```

Comment: This is a job for full-text searching. Read about it in the MySQL documentation.

Answer (score 2):

As Barmar says you can use full text functions:

```
SELECT id, customer_id, phrase 
FROM table
WHERE MATCH(phrase) AGAINST ('me wall like king apple');
```

If need to search on another column too then add it to `MATCH`:

```
SELECT id, customer_id, phrase 
FROM table
WHERE MATCH(phrase,keywords) AGAINST ('me wall like king apple');
```

Edit:

For the point 3 you can use the same functions:

```
SELECT id, customer_id, phrase, MATCH(phrase,keywords) AGAINST ('me wall like king apple') as score 
FROM table
WHERE MATCH(phrase,keywords) AGAINST ('me wall like king apple') 
ORDER BY score 
LIMIT 3;
```

This query will return the three best matches

For more information [take a look to the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html)

**UPDATE:**

According to manual:

> Some words are ignored in full-text searches:
>
> - Any word that is too short is ignored. The default minimum length of words that are found by full-text searches is four characters.
> - Words in the stopword list are ignored. A stopword is a word such as “the” or “some” that is so common that it is considered to have zero semantic value. There is a built-in stopword list, but it can be overwritten by a user-defined list.

You are using a short word to search with, this is why you didn't getting any result.

**UPDATE 09-09-14:**

From [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html):

> If you modify full-text variables that affect indexing (`ft_min_word_len`, `ft_max_word_len`, or `ft_stopword_file`), or if you change the stopword file itself, you must rebuild your `FULLTEXT` indexes after making the changes and restarting the server. To rebuild the indexes in this case, it is sufficient to do a `QUICK` repair operation:
>
> mysql> **REPAIR TABLE tbl_name QUICK;**

So, after executing `ALTER TABLE table ADD FULLTEXT(phrase, keywords);` you must execute `REPAIR TABLE tbl_name QUICK;` but **only once**

Comment: Thank you! I tried going with option 3, but received the following error: Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list. Any advice on why?

Comment: You need to execute this: `ALTER TABLE table ADD FULLTEXT(phrase, keywords);`

Comment: Just did that. It now works fine without phrasing problems, but no result is returned when the search is being conducted. Can I invite you to take a look at the question update? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you. Anyway to override the short search ignored rule? Reason is that keyword being searched are tags and sometimes they are indeed short: "IE", "Alt", "F6" and such. I'm reading the manual at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html but am a bit lost

Comment: I never tune it, but according to docs you can define the length of full text word. Add this to my.cnf file `[mysqld]
ft_min_word_len=1`.

Comment: I tried it already and restarted apache...still not working. Thanks though!

Comment: I almost made it, but stuck at last step where I would need to "rebuild the fulltext index". Does it mean I need to do something like:         $sql="alter table 'game' add fulltext(tags,message)";
        $this->db->query("alter table game add fulltext(tags,message)");

Answer (score 0):

```
  $keywords=explode(' ', $keywords_raw);
  if(count($keywords)>1)
                 {
                     $stmt.="(";
                     $i=0;
                     foreach($arr_s1 as $kv)
                     {
                        if($i>0)
                        {
                                $stmt.=" AND ";
                        }
                        $stmt.=" phrase like '%".$kv."%'";                       
                        $i++;
                     }
                     $stmt.=")";                    

                 }
```

Hope it will work for you.